# Получение указателя на элемент map во время ее обхода

Tags: golang

Как получить указатель на элемент map во время ее обхода?
В коде ниже все время выводится последний элемент (по всей видимости переменная `val` постоянно перезаписывается новым значением и указатель ведет на нее, а не на копию)

```
var testmap = map[string]int{
    "one":   1,
    "two":   2,
    "three": 3,
}

func getOne() (one *int) {
    for _, val := range testmap {
        if val == 1 {
            one = &val
        }
    }

    return one
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(*getOne()) // Выведет 3
}
```

Можно написать что-то типа такого

```
func getOne() (one *int) {
    for key, val := range testmap {
        if val == 1 {
            extra := testmap[key]
            one = &extra
        }
    }

    return one
}
```

Оно будет работать, но выглядит как-то костыльно и фактически ведет не на элемент map, а на его копию. Есть ли более простые способы получить указатель на элемент map?

Comment: Совет на будущее: *никогда* не берите адрес переменных из `range`, всегда копируйте переменную прежде, чем взять адрес. Самые непонятные баги возникают из-за того, что люди не понимают, что адрес один и тот же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Элементы отображения при его росте могут перемещаться в другие участки памяти. Из-за этого получать на них указатели в go запрещено. Если ваши значения достаточно большие, то просто храните в отображении указатели на них.